# How to group by container with their date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a query to display the number of containers that only contain products so the date is less than 01/01/2019.

Example:

my table : tab

| Num_Container | Num_Product | Date_Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 01/01/2020 |
| 1 | A2 | 01/01/2018 |
| 1 | A3 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | A4 | 01/01/2017 |
| 2 | A5 | 01/01/2018 |
| 2 | A6 | 01/01/2019 |
| 3 | A7 | 01/01/2022 |
| 3 | A8 | 01/01/2019 |
| 3 | A9 | 01/01/2016 |

The expected result is:

| Num_Container |
| --- |
| 2 |

The containers must contain only products less than or equal to the date 01/01/2019.

Comment: But what about (3, A7, 01/01/2022) ? ...

Comment: Please **do not ask question with capital letters only**. What have you tried to solve the problem ?

Comment: Tip: use `having` clause and `max` aggregate function. Your expected output doesn't satisfy that condition, because there are products from 2022 in container number 3.

Comment: Yes excuse me, The expected result is: Num_Container =2

Comment: @Ergest Basha I can correct the content of my post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select Num_Container
from test_tbl
group by Num_Container
having max(Date_Product) <= '01/01/2019' and min(Date_Product)<= '01/01/2019';
```

Result:

```
NUM_CONTAINER
2
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5e1914e32deecb371ae48ed9cb64a660)

Or in your case only `MAX` date is sufficient

```
select Num_Container
from test_tbl
group by Num_Container
having max(Date_Product) <= '01/01/2019' ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1464a7890ee71325bca90a36b728781f)

Comment: please i want to add a condition on not null dates,
what instruction should I put ?

Comment: i want to add Date_Product is not null in grouping condition

Comment: @razfun like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b18bfcf48d12d90dd93693af2d477769 ?

Answer (score 0):

This SQL statement can be a solution:

```
select num_container
  from your_table
 group by num_container
 having max(date_product) <= date '2019-01-01'
 order by num_container;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the query is good except the date format is not compatible.

Comment: I think if you write: date '2019-01-01', then it must be compatible. Perhaps our configuration is different.